# Cannot expand/enlarge or add new partition

Tags: macos, partitioning

When I first got my MBP, I reserved a 120GB partition in the SSD as I plan on installing Bootcamp. Now I no longer want to install Bootcamp so I want to recover the 120GB but found that I have no way to do so.

I'm running OS X 10.9.5, Mavericks.

[image]

Disk Utility is not giving me an option to resize my primary partition. I tried creating a new partition. It appears to be "preparing to partition disk" but nothing have happened for 1.5 hours.

[image]

I'm confused. I thought this is something very simple. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to merge I think. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76008/how-to-resize-macintosh-hd

Comment: Try to boot from your recovery partition (if you got one, otherwise you could boot from a USB stick or network) and resize from there. I vaguely remember not being able to resize the partition you booted the OS from, though this was a long time ago and may have changed.